# Sharing instance of proxy object across processes results in pickle errors

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to implement a simple shared object system in python between several processes.
I'm doing the following:

```
import os
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        manager = SyncManager(authkey=b'test')
        manager.start()
        address = manager.address
        d = manager.dict()
        pickled_dict = d.__reduce__()
        pickled_dict[1][-1]["authkey"] = b"test"
        print(pickled_dict)
        for i in range(1000):
            d[i] = i
    
        child_id = os.fork()
    
        if child_id != 0:
            # in parent, do work on the proxy object forever
            i = 0
            while True:
                d[i%1000] = i%3434
                i += 1
        else:
            # in children
    
            # connect to manager process
            child_manager = SyncManager(address=address, authkey=b'test')
            child_manager.connect()
    
            # rebuild the dictionary proxy
            proxy_obj = pickled_dict[0](*pickled_dict[1])
    
            # read on the proxy object forever
            while True:
                print(list(proxy_obj.values())[:10])
```

However on Python 3.9, this keeps failing for various pickle errors, like `_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x0a'.`

Am I doing something incorrect here? AFAIK it should be possible to read/write concurrently (several processes) from/to a Manager object
(FYI I've created an issue on Python too: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/101320 but no answer yet)

Comment: this has nothing to do with the manager itself, and more about the way os.fork works, you are in fact inheriting the same sockets that are used in the parent (the socket buffer) and some "thread local objects" that you aren't supposed to inherit, and this is something that the multiprocessing module handles, using os.fork manually is not recommended, this is not a bug, your code just lacks the means to make a "safe python fork".

Comment: creating the other `child_manager` has no effect as the object will find out that it was spawned from `manager` not `child_manager`, because of how fork keeps the global state of the python interpreter, which includes an active socket connection.

Comment: @AhmedAEK I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "includes an active socket connection.". Here the new connection in child process will create a new socket python object. You're saying that because the parent process has an active socket open, the new socket object will be the same OS socket object reused under the hood ? I don't see anything in the doc that indicates this

Comment: This is how `fork` works, it's a system call that has nothing to do with python, it duplicates everything, including handles and sockets, python multiprocessing modules does extra "cleanup", but you are not using it, you are using the raw C fork.

Comment: You could do the extra cleanup done by the multiprocessing module to get this code to work ... But that's just rewriting code that already exists.... `os.fork` lies in the heart of the multiprocessing module, and you aren't supposed to use it directly unless you are trying to override the behaviour of the multiprocessing module itself.

Comment: @AhmedAEK I don't agree. As I said, in the child process, the fact that I create a new SyncManager will create a new socket object. I don't see why creating a new socket object would reuse the old OS-level socket object that was initially created in initial process

Comment: You don't have to agree, that's what's happening under the hood whether or not you agree with it, as i have already said your new connection has no effect on the already created object, that's reusing the already created inherited socket, that you didn't cleanup.

Comment: New syncmanager instance in child process is creating a new connection object, which is in turn calling socket.socket(....) . This is documented https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#creating-sockets as creating a new file descriptor, so I don't see what is being reused in the child process

Comment: That is not the socket used by the `proxy_obj`, it wasn't created from `child_manager`, it was created from `manager` which was in fact inherited.

Comment: Again, I don't think so, the proxy_obj was pickled and it has no reference to the initial socket.  All it gets is an adress, and then this is re-created through https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/27e59afa2ad98e6bfe26c6b2b7f6294fa561680c/Lib/multiprocessing/connection.py#L583 . As you can see it calls socket.bind()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code I am presenting below will probably be very familiar to you and so I am telling you something you may already know. But there's not much harm in that except for the 5 minutes you might have "wasted" in reading this. Even then perhaps you will find something of value.

I really see no need for you to be using the low-level calls `__reduce__` and `fork` and so this answer does not attempt to get these calls to work for you. However, it does address what I understand to be your principal objective, i.e. "... trying to implement a simple shared object system in python between several processes" by showing how a multi-platform solution can be achieved.

The following code creates a new process in a platform-independent way and relies on Python knowing how to serialize a proxy object. I have also modified your code so that it does not run indefinitely:

```py
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager
from multiprocessing import Process

def child_process(address, proxy_obj):
    child_manager = SyncManager(address=address, authkey=b'test')
    child_manager.connect()

    print(list(proxy_obj.values())[:10])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with SyncManager(authkey=b'test') as manager:
        address = manager.address
        # Instead of making 1000 slow calls on a proxy,
        # do this instead:
        d = manager.dict({i: i for i in range(1000)})
        p = Process(target=child_process, args=(address, d))
        p.start()
        p.join()
```

Prints:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

**Note:**

You say, "... it should be possible to read/write concurrently (several processes) from/to a Manager object" -- and it is! Every call on a proxy object results in the call and its arguments being serialized and sent to the Manager's process to be de-serialized and executed by a thread. So as long as the calls are thread-safe there should be no issue and that is the case with a managed dictionary whose underlying implementation is a standard dictionary. But consider the case where your client processes are executing code as follows:

```py
proxy_obj[i] += 1
```

If it is possible for multiple processes to be trying to increment the same value, then it needs to be done under control of a `multiprocessing.Lock` instance because incrementing a dictionary value requires two successive calls on the dictionary, i.e. one to retrieve the current value and one to update the dictionary with the incremented value. So whenever your updates are not atomic you will need to treat the update as a *critical section* whose execution must be serialized. For example,

```py
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock

def child_process(address, proxy_obj, lock):
    child_manager = SyncManager(address=address, authkey=b'test')
    child_manager.connect()

    for i in range(10):
        with lock:
            proxy_obj[i] += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with SyncManager(authkey=b'test') as manager:
        address = manager.address
        d = manager.dict({i: i for i in range(10)})
        lock = Lock()
        p = Process(target=child_process, args=(address, d, lock))
        p.start()
        for i in range(10):
            with lock:
                d[i] += 1
        p.join()
        print(list(d.values()))
```

Prints:

```None
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Answer (score 1):

as already mentioned in the comments the problem is that both the parent and the child are using the same underlying OS socket buffer for communication, as this is the default behavior of the raw C `os.fork` that you are using (which is only defined by the operating system, not python), and shouldn't be used in standard python code. you should instead use the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module as it does extra "cleanup" to make sure these bugs won't happen.

in this case the "cleanup" is simply clearing the `multiprocessing.managers.BaseProxy._address_to_local` dictionary which has the socket in the parent, which is saved as a part of python's global state, which gets inherited along with the open socket connection.

```py
import os
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager
import multiprocessing.managers

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = SyncManager(authkey=b'test')
    manager.start()
    address = manager.address
    d = manager.dict()
    pickled_dict = d.__reduce__()
    pickled_dict[1][-1]["authkey"] = b"test"
    print(pickled_dict)
    for i in range(1000):
        d[i] = i

    child_id = os.fork()

    if child_id != 0:
        # in parent, do work on the proxy object forever
        i = 0
        while True:
            d[i % 1000] = i % 3434
            i += 1
    else:
        # in children
        multiprocessing.managers._address_to_local.clear()

        # rebuild the dictionary proxy
        proxy_obj = pickled_dict[0](*pickled_dict[1])

        # read on the proxy object forever
        while True:
            print(list(proxy_obj.values())[:10])
```

note that this will raise another error when the child tries to terminate as it will be trying to join the `manager` that it also inherited, because its reference wasn't cleaned up, but this is not going to crash your application, if only there was a builtin module that would do all of that for your ... oh right, there is.

python `os` module implementation is defined to be os dependent, which only provides wrappers for OS functionalities, it doesn't need the safety and portability of other modules.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can use managed objects with raw `os.fork()`.  It just takes some special handling.

The reason for your pickle errors is because of reusing connections.  d has a connection to manager inside it.  When you access d / proxy_obj, you're reusing that connection (child manager doesn't change that).  Just call d._connect () in child and pickle errors will go away.

Here's what should be changed :

- There's no need for child_manager.  Parent manager is a separate process that controls access to your shared dict.  Proxy objects already contain a connection to the manager.  child_manager is only needed if you were creating new shared objects in child but wanted parent manager to control them.  That's not the case here.
- You don't need to extract manager.address or authkey.  Manager puts copies of those in proxy objects it creates.  See d._authkey and d._token.address.
- Shared objects like d are meant to be shared (serialized) or inherited.  There's no need to manually pickle and rebuild d.  Just inherit d directly.
- As Ahmed notes, inheriting d misses the setup / cleanup hooks normally called when d is passed to Process.  That's fine, you can manually call them in child.  Just use d._connect () to create a new connection from d to manager.  Inheriting the parent connection in d causes pickle errors and [connection will eventually deadlock](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/101320#issuecomment-1685417037).
- You should really use os._exit () in a forked child so child doesn't cleanup / close resources in the parent.  Not really a problem in this short example, since child loops forever and parent doesn't have many resources.  In more complex programs it's an issue.

With that in mind, here's the revised code.

```
import os
import time
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    manager = SyncManager  (authkey=b'test')
    manager.start ()

    d = manager.dict ()
    for i in range (1000) :
        d [i] = i

    child_id = os.fork ()

    if child_id :   # in parent

        # do work on the proxy object forever
        i = 0
        while True :
            d [i % 1000] = i % 3434
            i += 1

    else :  # in child

        try :
            # reestablish new connection to manager instead of inherited connection
            d._connect  ()

            # read proxy object forever
            while True :
                print (list (d.values ()) [ :10])
                time.sleep (0.5)  # small time delay to avoid flooding console

        finally :
            os._exit ()
```

Output :

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[2264, 2265, 2266, 2267, 2268, 2269, 2270, 2271, 2272, 2273]
[2094, 2095, 2096, 2097, 2098, 2099, 2100, 2101, 2102, 2103]
[1924, 1925, 1926, 1927, 1928, 1929, 1930, 1931, 1932, 1933]
[1754, 1755, 1756, 1757, 1758, 1759, 1760, 1761, 1762, 1763]
[1584, 1585, 1586, 1587, 1588, 1589, 1590, 1591, 1592, 1593]
[414, 415, 416, 417, 418, 419, 420, 421, 422, 423]
[244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253]
[74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83]
[2338, 2339, 2340, 2341, 2342, 2343, 2344, 2345, 2346, 2347]
```